# HTML & CSS set width of space around items in percents or viewport width

Tags: html, css

Hello I am trying to set same width of flex items, so width of `.flexbox` going to be same width as `.width-example`, which will be in **%** or **vw**

Here is simple example how it shoud looks like:

[image]

```css
.width-example {
  width: 80%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  justify-content:  space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-item {
  width: 175px;
  height: 175px;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="width-example"> </div> 

<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  justify-content:  space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items:center;
  width:80%;
}
.width-example {
  width: 80%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  align-items:center;
}
```

This should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a width on the `.width-example` but not your `.flexbox`. Add a `width` and a `margin` to your `.flexbox`

```
.flexbox {
    display: flex;
    justify-content:  space-around;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```